# Itext: convert HTML img tag to PDF without having a page break

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I would like to convert the following HTML to PDF, where the image should be just below the text:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            I WANT THE IMAGE UNDER THIS TEXT!! 
        </div>
        <div>
            <img width="500px" src="http://www.tabletwritings.com/sites/default/files/pictures/History-of-the-Tablet.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        ciao
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the Java code for the conversion:

```
String inputFile = "input/pub.html";
String url = new File(inputFile).getPath();
String outputFile = "output/pub.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(url);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);        
os.close();
```

And this is the PDF output

http://issuu.com/matteotiberio/docs/output

The problem is that there is a page break before the image. 
I also tried to use the css properties 'page-break-before' and 'page-break-after', but the result is not as expected.